# HOW TO CREATE PROCEDURE TO execute queries from another input query string in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a procedure which accept a string as query0 generating a number of queries then execute them:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    PROCEDURE `zzz_test`.`nest_query`(IN qry_str VARCHAR(65535))

    BEGIN
        DECLARE bDone INT;
        
        DECLARE qry VARCHAR(65535);
        SET @query0 = qry_str;
        PREPARE stmt0 FROM @query;
        DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  stmt0;
        
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;
        
        OPEN curs;
        SET bDone = 0;
        REPEAT
            FETCH curs INTO qry;
            SET @query = qry;
            PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
            EXECUTE stmt;
        UNTIL bDONE END REPEAT;
        CLOSE curs;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

However, it prompt error as below:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  stmt0;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SE' at line 10
```

What's wrong with my code? Or is it possible?

Before working on above case, I have create another procedure with fixed query successfully as below:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `zzz_test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test2`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test2`()
BEGIN
        DECLARE bDone INT;
        
        DECLARE qry VARCHAR(65535);
        DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO zzz_test.test2 SELECT "',TABLE_NAME,'" as tb_name, ... FROM zzz_test0.',TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='zzz_test0';
        
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;
        
        OPEN curs;
        SET bDone = 0;
        REPEAT
            FETCH curs INTO qry;
            SET @query = qry;
            PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
            EXECUTE stmt;
        UNTIL bDONE END REPEAT;
        CLOSE curs;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: DECLARE must be placed at the top of BEGIN-END. Whereas you put some of them after SET and PREPARE. Add nested BEGIN-END if needed.

Comment: Also you cannot define cursor from the SQL stored in the variable or from prepared statement.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use dynamic SQL with a cursor. It is unclear why you want to use cursor or a stored procedure as is gives no advantage for you.